# Things you've believed for a long time were true, but are false in reality

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Do you have any things (mathematical statements, statements *about* mathematics) you've believed for a long time were true, but now with enough mathematical knowledge you realize were wrong? For example, my high school teacher used to tell the class that all there is to discover in math has already been discovered. Obviously, now, thinking about her statement makes me laugh out loud. What stories do you have?

Comment: See [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) at MO.

Comment: Have you considered returning to your high school to explain to your former teacher that what you were told is wrong? That's if the teacher is still working there.

Comment: *all there is to discover has already been discovered.* Diagnosis: [Philistinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistinism) brought on by chronic ignorance. Highly contagious, but luckily some are naturally immune.